# 1st page missing in built pdf

Tags: titles

In the below MWE, when I try to build the pdf, I am not able to see the 1st page i.e title and author's name and I just see the bib entry. The cls file can be downloaded from http://www.inderscience.com/www/download/latex-double-column.zip Can someone please help me resolve this error.

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{doublecol-new}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{natbib,stfloats}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}

\makeatletter
\def\theequation{\arabic{equation}}


\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setcounter{page}{1}

\LRH{F. Wang et~al.}

\RRH{Metadata Based Management and Sharing of Distributed Biomedical
Data}

\VOL{x}

\ISSUE{x}

\PUBYEAR{xxxx}

\BottomCatch

%\CLline

\PUBYEAR{201X}

\subtitle{}

\title{Metadata Based Management and Sharing of Distributed Biomedical Data}

%
\authorA{Fusheng Wang}
%
\affA{Department of Biomedical Informatics,\\ Emory University,\\ Atlanta, GA, USA \\
Fax: +1 \qquad E-mail: fusheng.wang@emory.edu}
%
%
\authorB{Fusheng Wang}
\affB{Department of Biomedical Informatics,\\ Emory University,\\ Atlanta, GA, USA \\
Fax: +1 \qquad E-mail: fusheng.wang@emory.edu}

\authorC{Peiya Liu}
\affC{Department of Integrated Data Systems, Siemens Corporate
Research \newline 755 College Road East, Princeton 08540, USA}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}


\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Myneni and Patel}{2010}]{myneni10col}
Myneni, S. and  Patel, V.L. (2010) 'Organization of biomedical data
for collaborative scientific research: a research information
management system', {\it International Journal of Information
Management}, Vol. 30, No. 3, pp.256--264



 \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What supposed to be in the first page?

Answer (score 1):

You have removed the command:

```
\maketitle
```

from your given code.

Add it before Abstract

Comment: Adding the \maketitle just before the abstract gives me "100 consecutive dead cycles \maketitle" error.

Comment: It works on mine... Just giving a warning yhat using leqno.clo instead leqno.sty and another about the name of the class provided that is not the same with the .sty file. Did you tried in the code you posted? or on another extended?

Comment: Which latex editor are you using? I added \maketitle in the same code that I posted.

Comment: I use texlive in kile editor on debian... It works on mine... I can not understand what you are missing. I will test again from ubuntu. But it is not a codes problem.